# Select table-specific column

Tags: sqlite

I have columns in multiple differents tables with the same name. I use JavaScript to send an object containing the fields, the `Node.js` package creates an array with the names, therefore if two columns have the same name, the value of the last one seems to be put in the array.

I had this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM FACTURATION AS F 
LEFT JOIN ENREGISTREMENT AS E ON F.Enregistrement=E.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESTITUTION AS R ON F.Restitution=R.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION AS X ON F.Numero=X.Facturation 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS C ON X.Numero_Client=C.Numero
```

Which returns my values. Knowing that `Select *` is not a good practice, i changed it to

```
SELECT Nom, Caution, Kilometrage 
FROM FACTURATION AS F 
LEFT JOIN ENREGISTREMENT AS E ON F.Enregistrement=E.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESTITUTION AS R ON F.Restitution=R.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION AS X ON F.Numero=X.Facturation 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS C ON X.Numero_Client=C.Numero
```

And it also works fine. But then i needed to differentiate the two columns from the different tables. I tried

```
SELECT CLIENT.Nom, ENREGISTREMENT.Caution, ENREGISTREMENT.Kilometrage 
FROM FACTURATION AS F 
LEFT JOIN ENREGISTREMENT AS E ON F.Enregistrement=E.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESTITUTION AS R ON F.Restitution=R.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION AS X ON F.Numero=X.Facturation 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS C ON X.Numero_Client=C.Numero
```

And it returns nothing. Even if i only select `CLIENT.Nom` it does not work while selecting `Nom` works fine.
I use the `sqlite3` package from `Node Package Manager`

Comment: What happens if you change to `SELECT C.Nom, E.Caution, E.Kilometrage` ?

Comment: It works ... And now i feel stupid and yet i don't know why it works like that. Do the alias completely replace the original name ? Or is there some obscure reason why i cannot use the full name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the tablename you can use the alias names for the columnnames.

```
SELECT C.Nom, E.Caution, E.Kilometrage 
FROM FACTURATION AS F 
LEFT JOIN ENREGISTREMENT AS E ON F.Enregistrement=E.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESTITUTION AS R ON F.Restitution=R.Numero 
LEFT JOIN RESERVATION AS X ON F.Numero=X.Facturation 
LEFT JOIN CLIENT AS C ON X.Numero_Client=C.Numero
```